Probability estimation of winner between 3 people
There is an obstacle course. Alice beats Bob 60% of the time. Bob beats Charlie 60% of the time. Estimate how often Alice beats Charlie.
My approach is as follows:
Suppose 100 trials of the obstacle course are played.
In 60 of these we expect Alice to beat Bob.
In 60% of the above 60 (so in 36 of these), we expect Bob to beat Charlie giving us 36 trials where Alice beats Charlie.
In 40% of the above 60 (so in 24 of these), we expect Charlie to beat Bob. Thus, here both Alice and Charlie beat Bob.
Assuming a 50/50 split between Alice and Charlie, we add in 12 more wins for Alice where she beats Charlie.
In the remaining 40 trials, we expect Bob to beat Alice.
In 60% of the above (so in 24 of these), we expect Bob to beat Charlie as well. So both Alice and Charlie lose to Bob.
Assuming a 50/50 split between Alice and Charlie, we add in 12 more wins for Alice where she beats Charlie.
In 40% of the above (so in 16 of these), we expect Charlie to beat Bob and so he also beats Alice here.
Thus, Alice will beat Charlie in 36+12+12 = 60 trials or 60% of the time.
Is this right?
I'm not sure what else to go on?

There is no "answer" to this.  Rather, you need to model the process and use your model to make predictions (which, of course, might be wrong).   A simple model might have three mean speeds and three mean sigmas.  Of course, you don't have enough data to fit $6$ parameters so you'll need to make some guesses.  And, of course, there might be correlations, but again you have very little data to work with.

Note that your answer seems too low.  After all, $B$ beats $C$ $60%$ of the time and $A$ is usually faster than $B$, so one might expect $A$ to beat $C$ more often than $B$ does.

Key point: You are assuming the speeds are independent when there is no reason to do so

Partial answer
Assuming that ties aren't allowed, there are 6 possible orders in which the three competitors can finish.  Let $p_1$ thru $p_6$ be the probabilities of each one.

$p_1$ : Alice > Bob > Charlie
$p_2$ : Alice > Charlie > Bob
$p_3$ : Bob > Alice > Charlie
$p_4$ : Bob > Charlie > Alice
$p_5$ : Charlie > Alice > Bob
$p_6$ : Charlie > Bob > Alice

We know that:

$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 + p_5 + p_6 = 1$ (The above list of outcomes is exhaustive.)
$p_1 + p_2 + p_5 = 0.6$ (Alice beats Bob 60% of the time.)
$p_1 + p_3 + p_4 = 0.6$ (Bob beats Charlie 60% of the time.)

And we want to find $p_1 + p_2 + p_3$, the probability that Alice beats Charlie.
The problem is, we have only 3 equations for 6 variables.  Thus, there is no unique solution unless you make additional assumptions.
You can combine the equations (#2 + #3 - #1) get $p_1 - p_6 = 0.2$, which implies that $p_1 \ge 0.2$, and thus the desired probability ($p_1 + p_2 + p_3$) must be at least 20%.  But its true value could be anything between 20% and 100%, as demonstrated by @Henry's answer.

Giving numerical examples based on Dan's answer, one extreme is that Alice beats Charlie $100\%$ of the time, for example with

$20\%$ : Alice > Bob > Charlie
$40\%$ : Alice > Charlie > Bob
$40\%$ : Bob > Alice > Charlie
$\,\,\,0\%$ : Bob > Charlie > Alice
$\,\,\,0\%$ : Charlie > Alice > Bob
$\,\,\,0\%$ : Charlie > Bob > Alice

Another extreme is that Alice beats Charlie $20\%$ of the time, for example with

$20\%$ : Alice > Bob > Charlie
$\,\,\,0\%$ : Alice > Charlie > Bob
$\,\,\,0\%$ : Bob > Alice > Charlie
$40\%$ : Bob > Charlie > Alice
$40\%$ : Charlie > Alice > Bob
$\,\,\,0\%$ : Charlie > Bob > Alice

You can achieve any intermediate figure, for example but not necessarily by taking a weighted average of those two patterns.  Other patterns are also possible, though they are constrained, e.g. with the probability of Alice > Bob > Charlie necessarily being $20$ percentage points higher than the probability of Charlie > Bob > Alice, which is why the probability of Alice beating Charlie must be at least $20\%$.
